# Statistics for list

Tags: r, list, statistics, standard-error

I have the following list in R. I would like to calculate standard error in each percentage tile. How do I do this?

```
[[1]]
25% 50% 75% 90% 
 -4  -2  -3  -3 

[[2]]
25% 50% 75% 90% 
 -4  -2  -3  -2 

[[3]]
25% 50% 75% 90% 
 -4  -2  -2  -2 

[[4]]
25% 50% 75% 90% 
 -4  -2  -3  -2 

[[5]]
25% 50% 75% 90% 
 -4  -2  -2  -2
```

**Background Info**

I got these values from bootstrap simulations. `est` is a function of the estimates. I can omit `name` of the list. I want to get standard errors of vertical numbers.

```
eachIter[[i]] = est(boot.y00, boot.y01, boot.y10, boot.y11)
```

```
[[1]]
[1] -4 -2 -2 -1

[[2]]
[1] -4 -2 -2 -2

[[3]]
[1] -4 -2 -2 -3

[[4]]
[1] -3 -1 -3 -2

[[5]]
[1] -4 -2 -2 -3
```

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Try `apply(do.call(the_list, rbind.data.frame), 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)`.